# Match word boundary before non-alphanumerical character

Tags: python, regex

I want to find words starting with a single non-alphanumerical character, say `'$'`, in a string with `re.findall`

#### Example of matching words

```
$Python
$foo
$any_word123
```

#### Example of non-matching words

```
$$Python
foo
foo$bar
```

#### Why `\b` does not work

If the first character were to be alphanumerical, I could do this.

```
re.findall(r'\bA\w+', s)
```

But this does not work for a pattern like `\b\$\w+` because `\b` matches the empty string only between a `\w` and a `\W`.

```
# The line below matches only the last '$baz' which is the one that should not be matched
re.findall(r'\b\$\w+', '$foo $bar x$baz').
```

The above outputs `['$baz']`, but the desired pattern should output `['$foo', '$bar']`.

I tried replacing `\b` by a positive lookbehind with pattern `^|\s`, but this does not work because *lookarounds* must be fixed in length.

What is the correct way to handle this pattern?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: maybe `re.findall(r'(?:\b|^)\$\w+', '$a $a x$a')`?

Comment: Correct, I just figured out that negative lookbehind works: `(?<!\S)\$\w+`

Comment: your example is bad. use a pattern like `$a $b x$c` instead

Comment: @coldspeed that did not work because it matches the space before.

Comment: it returns `['$a', '$a']` for me.

Comment: @coldspeed not the correct $a s :) try with my input ($a $b x$c)

Comment: @coldspeed Oh, you used a non capturing group! Yes that works too.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'(?<!\w)\$\w+', s)` as `$` is non-word character and `\b` before `$` won't match

Comment: @anubhava it's close enough, I just use \S for the lookbehind instead not to match a word like '$$a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will match a word starting with a single non-alphanumerical character.

```
re.findall(r'''
(?:     # start non-capturing group
  ^         # start of string
  |         # or
  \s        # space character
)       # end non-capturing group
(       # start capturing group
  [^\w\s]   # character that is not a word or space character
  \w+       # one or more word characters
)       # end capturing group
''', s, re.X)
```

or just:

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)([^\w\s]\w+)', s, re.X)
```

results in:

```
'$a $b a$c $$d' -> ['$a', '$b']
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a negative lookbehind with the non-whitespace metacharacter `\S`.

```
s = '$Python $foo foo$bar baz'

re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\$\w+', s) # output: ['$Python', '$foo']
```

Comment: Ok understood then `\b` (word boundary) wasn't the right choice for you regex in first place since `\bA\w+` would also match `-Afoo`